# Swift: Reset a View Controller within a View Hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss, uiview-hierarchy

I am trying to completely reset `Game` when `Endgame Screen` is dismissed and the view goes back to `Game`. I have tried dismissing `Game` but it also get rids of `EndgameScreen`. I have even gone as far as presenting the `EndgameScreen` from the `Menu` view controller, but it does not bring a nice result.
[image]

Thanks to anyone who can help, I've been working on this for days!

Comment: Why is removing the endgame screen a problem?

Comment: The user interacts with that screen. It is dismissed when the retry button is pressed, but I want it to go back to a restarted `Game` view controller.

Comment: Is the problem that you're storing data about game state inside the game controller?

Comment: There is a bug that I am sending NSNotifications to the view controller, and If I don't dismiss the view controller, notifications are being sent to previous instances of that view controller.

Comment: Not a good solution. I am going to make an animation to cover up the issue